# Echo PHP variable using shortcode in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode

I want to echo PHP variable value on any page using shortcode in WordPress.

I have created:

```
function custom_shortcode() {

    echo $unique;

}
add_shortcode( 'test', 'custom_shortcode' );
```

When I place shortcode `[test]` on any page, it returns nothing.

The `$unique` variable is to show the logged-in user's username in URL. For example: `example.com/?username`

The expected output on front-end need to be: `example.com/?username`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
function custom_shortcode( $atts, $content = null )  {
    global $unique; // if $unique is global var add this line too
    return $unique;
}
add_shortcode( 'test', 'custom_shortcode' );
```